# Python Telegram Bot Suddenly Giving "Chat Not Found" Error

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've been using a simple bot (code below) for many months but it has recently stopped working. The bot is an admin of the group and I have sent a message to it. Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot(token='xxxxxxxxxxx')

bot.send_message("-1111111111", text="hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have a question about this bot and I doubt at all that it will work in this form... However, your error is most likely related to the fact that:

- the chat where the bot was the administrator was deleted
- the bot has been stripped of admin rights/removed from the chat

I recommend checking what the bot can get from your chat